# How do you make imageview open a link?

Tags: android, imageview

So when i run the emulator and click the imageview that i've made as a link, nothing happens. What am i doing wrong?

Below is both my .java and .xml

```
  @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_solar);
    
            ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    
            img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
                    intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://facebook.com"));
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        }
    
    
    
    
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:src="@drawable/facebookshare"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-85dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:onClick="v"
        />]
```

Comment: Can you post the whole xml?

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Comment: Hello @Adriaan - I am unable to delete this post- Could you delete it for me, please?

Comment: No, you cannot delete this. See the article I linked. There's an accepted answer, which means someone thought this post useful. Stack Overflow doesn't allow you to remove useful content. You can try filling out the [content form](https://stackoverflow.co/company/contact) to ask for disassociation with the post.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the onClick tag from image view in XML .